# Git - multiple machines per developer - committing across machines but not to main branch

Tags: php, git, version-control, branch, branching-and-merging

We are transitioning to git from SVN, and there's some concepts I can't wrap my head around.

We have a setup as follows:

- live server, "live"
- in-house dev server, "local" (git server, svn daemon, all repos reside on this one)
- workstations (iMacs)
- home computers (primarily linux PCs)

I've converted our source into a git repo, and committed it to "local". It all works well, and when I clone it it copies the master branch into my local environment, whether I'm home or at work. Pulling on the live server also works well, and it pulls the master branch changes into the live environment. But I want to have the following possibilities:

- I want to be able to develop and commit on the workstation without pushing to the master branch, but I would like these changes to be reflected on my home machine as well. In other words, I want to be able to make a partial update or feature, commit, and continue working on it at home without it ever being pulled into any kind of live branch. Is this accomplished with branching? To I commit and then push to a specific branch? Mind you, tracking the workstation git repository with the home computer is out of the question, since the workstation isn't always on (anyone who's ever run a java app on a Mac knows it can only stay on for a couple hours at most)
- I want each developer to be able to work on his own part of the application, without us depending on each other. Is it advisable to do this with per-dev-branches, or should we make per-feature-branches?
- When work on a feature is complete, is it advisable to merge the branch into the master repo, and then pull the master repo updates into the live environment, or should we have a separate "production" branch for these purposes? How is live-deployment via git usually handled? Since we have a release frequency of about 10 revisions per day (extremely rapid development cycles), SVN worked quite nicely so far in that our live site is just a checkout of the repository and whenever an update is ready, we just called svn update on those files on the live server. Any best practices regarding this with git?

Edit:

Practical example with my assumptions on how this all works: Let's say our project is "project", and we have developers "dev1", "dev2" and "dev3", each with 2 machines. The team has 3 tasks: "bug", "feature" and "collaboration". Bug is assigned to dev1, feature to dev2, and collaboration is a feature all three need to work on together ($REMOTE is the url of the main repo on our local dev server, i.e. user@local:repo.git):

=========

I. Working locally

Since dev1 is assigned to "bug", he will be taking care of that. He does the following:

```
$git branch bug
$git checkout bug // switches to bug branch
( // edit some files)
$git commit -a -m 'I fixed the bug!'
$git push $REMOTE bug
```

How does this developer now merge his fix into the master repo, and how does he delete the bug branch across all machines once this merge is done? I would like the bug branch to disappear when people do an update or fetch or whatever in case they checked it out or however you retrieve it.

========

II Working locally, and then continuing on the same synced branch on another location

"feature" has been assigned to "dev2" and he does this:

```
$git branch feature
$git checkout feature // switches to feature branch
( // edit/add some files etc. )
$git commit -a -m 'I made some updates, will continue at home'
$git push $REMOTE feature
// at home, the developer does the following, right?
$git clone $REMOTE -b feature /some_new_folder // if he didn't clone the whole repo previously
or
cd previously_cloned_repo_master_or_whatever
$git fetch
$git checkout $REMOTE feature
( // right? )
( // edit some files then ... )
$git commit -a m 'I finished!'
$git push
// Same as above, what next? How to merge it into all other branches and safely delete the branch afterwards. What happens when someone is in a branch that has been deleted, and makes a pull?
```

========

III Many people on one branch, separate from the master branch

"collaboration" is a joint effort, and will be worked on by all three devs from all 6 locations. It is created by dev3.

```
$git branch collaboration
$git checkout collaboration // switches to needed branch
( // add something, so we have something to commit)
$git commit -a -m 'Initialized new branch'
$git push $REMOTE collaboration
( // The other two devs can then simply call .. )
$git fetch
$git checkout $REMOTE collaboration
( // And they're ready to go, right? )
( // Each dev then makes his own edits on some areas, commits, and pushes. All pushes change the content of the branch, so that if dev2 pushed and dev1 makes $git pull in the root of the project while on this branch, dev1 will get his changes, right? )
```

========

Additionally, is it possible to restrict a branch to a specific branch creator? For example, I'd like to see what dev1 did on "bug" before he deletes it, but in case I want to make some of my own changes on it, I should NOT be allowed to do so, I should instead have to make a pull request for that given branch, and dev1 should have to manually accept my changes - I should not be able to force his hand on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Use [git flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/).

It'll remove questions and automate some of the things you're asking about. When you are familiar with git flow and branching etc. you can easily choose to do things differently - or manually.

**Changes to be reflected on my home machine as well**

On your imac push/pull to not-master and on your home machine push/pull from not-master.

Where "not-master" is whatever branch you're currently working on.

**Per dev branches**

Up to you, your workflow needs to aide not hinder development. E.g. what if two developers are collaborating on the same task - do you want to force them to work in different branches? Feature branches probably make more sense, there's nothing wrong with having user branches though.

**Separate production branch**

However you do it - **your live app should pull from a known stable tag/branch**, and normally **don't push directly to master**, because breaking things is part of development, but breaking the code your live app will pull from is something you absolutely want to avoid. You should be able to pull on your live install with absolutely no doubt, at any time, that you might be pulling in broken code. If you're using a [Continuous Integration server](http://jenkins-ci.org/) you can easily automate merging from your development branch to master if all the tests pass, and even automatically deploy.

**When a branch is finished with**

All of the workflow doubts are the same thing. when a branch is finished with, you merge it to your main branch.

i.e.

```
$ git branch working-on-this master
$ git add ...
$ git commit ...
$ # rinse and repeat
$ git push --set-upstream $REMOTE working-on-this
```

And when the time comes:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git pull
$ git merge working-on-this
$ git push
$ git branch -d working-on-this
$ git push $REMOTE :working-on-this
```

You don't explicitly delete all branches on other machines; however anyone at any time can run:

```
$ git branch --merged master
```

which if a branch is finished with will look like this:

```
$ git branch --merged master
master
working-on-this
$ git branch -d working-on-this
```

Which indicates that working-on-this can safely be deleted. In any event - `git branch -d` triggers a warning and aborts if you try to delete a branch that isn't merged with the branch you're on when you execute the command.

If you find you have multiple remote branches that are thought to already be finished - you can clean them up with one command:

```
$ git remote prune -n origin
```

The `-n` flag means it'll only report which branches it's going to delete - remove that flag to actually delete the obsolete remote branches

If you have several developers working on the same branch (collaboration) **communication is key** don't rely on a workflow, actively talk about deleting things before leaving one of your team working in an (allegedly) finished branch.

**Restricting branch commit permissions**

Yes you can do that - but do you really want to? You're better off using communication and conventions.

Some suggestions:

- anyone can create a remote branch
- nobody commits/merges to master (Only the lead dev does that)
- nobody deletes a remote branch (Only the lead dev does that)
- nobody prunes the remote server (Only the lead dev does that)

Anyone *can* at any time do any of the above , but assuming you trust your team as a whole, there's no reason to actually restrict developers to prevent them from doing so - there will probably be times where they need to break-ranks, and rules prevent that whereas a convention does not.

Comment: The first option is not viable due to our workstations being off during the rest of the day, as mentioned in the OP. 10 commits per day does mean 10 production updates per day, yes.

Comment: After every bigger commit, yes. It's very weird, yeah, and extremely frustrating. Alas, it's all up to one's superiors unfortunately. Anyway, thanks, I'm slowly grasping the branching thing. I edited the main question if you'd care to take a look, with some actual examples I intend to encounter. I just want to make sure I got the workflow right.

Comment: Ok, I got the gist. We set up everything according to git-flow, and we explored all the options, pretty awesome stuff. Works like a charm. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

> I want to be able to develop and commit..

Yes this is accomplished by branching. Initially you push up your entire branch from your workstation to "local" and you can then checkout a tracking branch at home if you want to continue working there.

> I want each developer to be..

I'd recommend feature branches rather than developer branches. It makes more sense when several developers are collaborating on a feature.

> When work on a feature is complete, is it advisable..

This is a matter of taste. We generally create a release branch first (I think many do), so we have a seam between the real live stuff and the things that needs to be tested, when the release branch is considered to be stable we merge that branch into master and then it can go live.

I don't think there are any best practices. It depends on what you are doing, i.e. what kind of stuff you are developing. If you want to keep your workflow git will allow you to do that. Instead of "svn update" you do "git pull".

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the main question with some actual examples I intend to encounter. Would you take a look please?

Answer (score 1):

You can introduce naming conventions for your branches and let them all live happily on `local`. For example:

At work:

```
work$ git branch -a
  master
* user1/my-work
  remote/local/master
  remote/local/user1/my-work
work$ git push local user1/my-work
```

and at home:

```
home$ git branch -a
  master
* user1/my-work
  remote/local/master
  remote/local/user1/my-work
home$ git pull local user1/my-work
```

Every user gets assigned a prefix for their branches, and so `local` can serve as central storage server of a kind.

Comment: Couldn't I just use "$git checkout mybranch" and "$git pull / push"
 instead of "pull / push local user1/mybranch"?